# Are there any drawbacks when I declare variables inside an IF body?

Tags: c, c89, variable-declaration

I have that functionality inside a function that is encapsulated within an `#ifdef` block that has an `if()` statement attached to it:

```
int myfunction(void) {
  int condition = 0;
#ifdef USE_WHATEVER
  int othervar  = 0;
#endif /* USE_WHATEVER */
  /* some code */
#ifdef USE_WHATEVER
  if( condition ) {
    othervar++;
    /* do other things with othervar */
  }
#endif /* USE_WHATEVER */
```

**The variable `othervar` is only used inside the `#ifdef` block. Since the whole `#ifdef` block is an `if` statement, I could pull the declaration of `othervar` inside the `if` block**:

```
int myfunction(void) {
  int condition = 0;
  /* some code */
#ifdef USE_WHATEVER
  if( condition ) {
    int othervar = 0;
    othervar++;
    /* do other things with othervar */
  }
#endif /* USE_WHATEVER */
```

This seems much cleaner to me than the first example. However, are there any drawbacks (performance, ...) of doing such?

Comment: I would be surprised if a compiler generated different code for these two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c89, variables can only be declared at the beginning of a block. Some ppl/coding standards would put all variable declarations at the top of the function, like you are seeing here. However, variables may be declared at the beginning of any block.

You need to consider the scope of `othervar`. If it is used only inside the `if` block then it is safe to move the declaration to the beginning of the `if` block.

There should not be any performance drawback. The compiler is not unlikely to generate the exact same code for the two cases.

Comment: Expected that but wasn't sure. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no drawback as such unless you want to use the variable within the block scope.The only problem is that this kind of definition i.e. definition of variable in between the code might not be accepted in some standard.